# IOS7 automatic resize UITableView on content change

Tags: ios7, tableview, autoresize

I'm trying to display a UIPickerview in a UITableView, as it is used in the Calendar app. This works fine. (described here: http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/)

Since I have more UI elements in the view, I can't use the UITableViewController. This leaves a large grey area to display the UIPickerView, which isn't used.

[image: no Picker displayed]

[image: with picker]

I'm using this, to set some options (limited number of optioncells < 5). Is there a possibility to auto-resize the UITableView, to be as large as needed? When the UIPickerView isn't displayed, the grey area will be only a little bit around the cells, and it expands when the UIPickerView is displayed.

Since this might resize the View to be larger than the screen, do I need a UIScrollView?

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT: changed pictures to display tableview and uipicker

Comment: Can you do a better job of explaining this?  I don't see a table view anywhere.  I don't see a picker view.  All I see is a textview and a tab bar.  Moreover, there's no outline around the primarily white image on the white website background.

Comment: I hope these pictures demonstrate better, what I mean.